# Display data from sqlite in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, simplecursoradapter, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor

I can display data from databases, but the data only read 1. How to display all data from databases?

Ex: for.do..while....?!

Here is my code:

```
public Button.OnClickListener btListner2=new Button.OnClickListener() {

    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) {           
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(DragListActivity.this, db_name);  
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();  
        Cursor cursor;  
        cursor = db.query("Direction", new String[]{"id","name"}, null, null, null, null, null);  
        cursor.moveToNext(); 
        String _id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));  
        System.out.println(_id);    
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));  
        System.out.println(name);
    }
};
```

> 02-04 18:04:38.123: D/TextLayoutCache(29904): Using debug level: 0 -
>   Debug Enabled: 0
>
> 02-04 18:04:41.273: I/System.out(29904): 1 02-04 18:04:41.273:
>   I/System.out(29904): 特約高雄三多 02-04 18:04:41.623: I/System.out(29904): 1
>   02-04 18:04:41.623: I/System.out(29904): 特約高雄三多 02-04 18:04:42.133:
>   I/System.out(29904): 1 02-04 18:04:42.133: I/System.out(29904): 特約高雄三多
>   02-04 18:04:42.663: I/System.out(29904): 1 02-04 18:04:42.663:
>   I/System.out(29904): 特約高雄三多 02-04 18:04:43.143: I/System.out(29904): 1
>   02-04 18:04:43.143: I/System.out(29904): 特約高雄三多

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the cursor with `moveTo...()` methods to get all result rows:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        String _id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));  
        System.out.println(_id);    
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));  
        System.out.println(name);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through all entries in your database.

Create an ArrayList and add your items to ArrayList

```
if (cursor.getCount() > 0) 
{
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do 
    {
       ArrayList<String> arr=new ArrayList<String>();
       arr.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```